# create array of existing buttons vb 2013

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I used to program in VB6 and am trying to write the same program in VB 2013.  In this program I use an array of 49 buttons that all do the same thing when you click on them.  I have figured out have to do the click function to a point:

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click, Button10.Click, Button11.Click, Button12.Click, Button13.Click, Button16.Click, Button17.Click, Button18.Click, Button19.Click, Button20.Click
   ...

End Sub
```

What I am trying to do is simplify the code down to using an array so I can just pass on the index.  One other person asked the same question in 2010 and the best answer was:

```
Button[] array = { firstButton, secondButton };
```

That would work but I want something with less typing.  I also tried the following with failure:

One

```
Button[] buttons = this.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToArray();
```

Two

```
For i = 1 To 100
  Dim btns() As Button = Controls.Find("Button" & i, True)
  Dim btn As Button
  If btns IsNot Nothing Then
    btn = btns(0)
    'If buttons Is Nothing Then
    '  ReDim buttons(0)
    'Else
    '  ReDim Preserve buttons(buttons.Length)
    'End If
    'buttons(UBound(buttons)) = btn
    btn.Text = i - 1 'here you can change whatever you want
  End If
Next
```

Three

```
Dim buttons() As Button

buttons = Nothing
For Each b As Button In Me.Controls
If buttons Is Nothing Then
    ReDim buttons(0)
Else
    ReDim Preserve buttons(buttons.Length)
End If
buttons(UBound(buttons)) = b
Next
```

I just can't get it to accept the existing buttons into an array.  I hope someone can help.

Comment: You should use a `List(Of Button)`.

Comment: Neither an array or List will do much to help.  VB.NET is not like VB6.  If what you want is `49 buttons that all do the same thing`, use a common event handler.

Comment: The common Event handler is what I started to do at the very beginning.  Correct?

Comment: yes, with the multiple Handles clauses.  you can also do that dynamically at runtime using `AddHandler`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option two will work, you just need to add the button found into a list. I suggest you add your buttons into a List(Of ) instead of an array. You can always convert the list into an array if you really need to.

```
    Dim buttonList As New List(Of Button)

    For i As Integer = 1 To 100
        Dim btns() As Control = Controls.Find("Button" & i, True)

        If btns IsNot Nothing AndAlso btns.Length > 0 Then
            buttonList.Add(CType(btns(0), Button))
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: I just used your code and got an error.  The error is:  'Controls' is not declared  Not sure if it matters but I am using Visual Studio 2013 Express?

Comment: @DuckyDarkling [Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls(v=vs.110).aspx) is a property of the form. If you are executing this outside the form you'll have to properly pass your form.

Comment: I did minor modification to your code and it works now.  I am now able to get my index from the button that is clicked and then modify that button and others through the list.  Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

If your `Button`s are nested inside container controls (e.g. a `GroupBox`) then you will need to perform a recursive search for all buttons.  Maybe something like this (totally unoptimized)...

```vb
Private Function FindAllButtons(root As Control) As List(Of Button)
    Dim result As List(Of Button) = New List(Of Button)()
    For Each c As Control In root.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is Button Then
            result.Add(DirectCast(c, Button))
        ElseIf c.HasChildren Then
            result.AddRange(FindAllButtons(c))
        End If
    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

Then just call that in your `Form`:

```vb
Dim allButtons as List(Of Button) = FindAllButtons(Me)
' Add common Click handler
For Each b As Button In allButtons
    AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
Next
```

**Update** Just for fun, here's a generic version to find other types of control.

```vb
Private Function FindAllControls(Of T As Control)(root As Control) As List(Of T)
    Dim result As List(Of T) = New List(Of T)()
    For Each c As Control In root.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is T Then
            result.Add(DirectCast(c, T))
        ElseIf c.HasChildren Then
            result.AddRange(FindAllControls(Of T)(c))
        End If
    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

You can use that like:

```vb
Dim allButtons As List(Of Button) = FindAllControls(Of Button)(Me)
Dim allTextBoxes As List(Of TextBox) = FindAllControls(Of TextBox)(Me)
```